# How can I split array of Numbers to individual digits in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, numbers

I have an array

```
const myArr = [ 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106 ]
```

I need to split into digits like this:

```
const splited = [ 9, 4, 9, 5, 9, 6, 9, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the items, split and map numbers.

```js
var array = [ 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106],
    pieces = array.join('').split('').map(Number);
    
console.log(pieces);
```

Same approach, different tools.

```js
var array = [ 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106],
    pieces = Array.from(array.join(''), Number);
    
console.log(pieces);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. The second option is very nice, I will remember it.

Answer (score 1):

`map` each number to a string and split the string, and spread the result into `[].concat` to flatten:

```js
const myArr = [ 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106 ];
const splitted = [].concat(...myArr.map(num => String(num).split('')));
console.log(splitted);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function to create a new array and use `split` to split the number converted to string

```js
const myArr = [94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106]

let newArr = myArr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  let tempArray = curr.toString().split('').map((item) => {
    return +item;

  });
  acc.push(...tempArray)
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArr)
```